# I found that Im(arcsin(R))=-arccosh(R). Is this true?

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

I made a general formula for $sin(z)=R$, and after looking at the imaginary part, I found that it exactly equaled $-arccosh(R)$. I was wondering if I did this correctly and if there is anything related:

1. General formula for $sin(z)=R$ (Based on a blackpenredpen video about sin(z)=2):

$sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$

$e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2iR$

$e^{iz}$ → $e^{2iz}-1=2iRe^{iz}$

$e^{2iz}-2iRe^{iz}-1=0$

$e^{iz}=iR\pm\sqrt{1-R^{2}}$

$iz=\ln\left(iR\pm\sqrt{1-R^{2}}\right)$

$iz=\ln\left(i\left(R\pm\sqrt{R^{2}-1}\right)\right)$

$iz=\ln\left(i\right)+\ln\left(R\pm\sqrt{R^{2}-1}\right)$

$iz=i\frac{\pi}{2}+\ln\left(R\pm\sqrt{R^{2}-1}\right)$

$z=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\ln\left(R\pm\sqrt{R^{2}-1}\right)$

I know I left out a +$2\pi n$, also this can be verified by plugging back into the complex sine formula

2. Using this equation to get to my equation

$z=\frac{\pi}{2}-i\ln\left(R\pm\sqrt{R^{2}-1}\right)$

$\Im (z)=-\ln\left(R\pm\sqrt{R^{2}-1}\right)$

After looking at this function in Desmos I realized that this is equal to   $-\pm\ arcosh(R)$

This is pretty weird and interesting so I was wondering if anyone could check my work to see if I'm right.
I was also wondering if this is useful at all, or if there is anything I could do with this.

Thanks!